# FFmpeg Images resize to fill with crop like `cover`

Tags: ffmpeg

Hello i have image sequence difference sizes (example 4 images screen1).
I want save aspect ratio to fill output size 300x400. If image side out - crop. In web it named 'image cover'.
need output result on screen2. Green brush say about side crop.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Example using [scale](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale), [crop](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop), and [xstack](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#xstack):

```
ffmpeg -i topleft.jpg -i topright.jpg -i bottomleft.jpg -i bottomright.jpg -filter_complex "[0]scale=150:200:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase,crop=150:200[tl];[1]scale=150:200:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase,crop=150:200:0:0[tr];[2]scale=150:200:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase,crop=150:200[bl];[3]scale=150:200:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase,crop=150:200[br];[tl][tr][bl][br]xstack=inputs=4:layout=0_0|w0_0|0_h0|w0_h0[v]" -map "[v]" -frames:v 1 output.jpg
```